# how to do a pinterest like theme with bootstrap 2.3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering how to do a dynamic html model first(ie. do I just need a list of the things that go in each pinterest like box)

Then once I have the model(I am guessing a straight list), how do I form a pinterest like page with twitter bootstrap.

Currently, we have one theme (we use complete separate html files for some themes) where we just have the controller form a model of List> rows and in the html we loop over the rows generating the correct twitter bootstrap html for each row and 3 columns.

I am wondering however how to do this with pinterest or should I be generating a model with just a List for a pinterest theme.

and maybe a side question, I wonder if I could have done a grid twitter bootstrap layout with 3 columns per row and just fed it a List but I didn't know how to do that either.

any guesses appreciated as I am not sure where to start here.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand right, Masorny plugin is the answer for your problem: http://masonry.desandro.com/